understanding the metric in a Fermi geodesic coordinate
Suppose $F:\mathbb{R}^N\to M$ determines a system of Fermi coordinates in a neighborhood of a closed nontrivial geodesic $\Gamma$ of arclength $2l$ in a smooth Riemannian $N+1$-manifold $(M,g)$. Mathematically for $\bar{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_{N-1})$ in local coordinates and letting $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$ a bounded domain with smooth boundary $$F(x_0,\bar{x}):=\exp_{\gamma(x_0)}^{\partial\Omega}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}x_iE_i\right)$$ where $E_i$ are orthonormal basis for the normal bundle $N_p\Gamma$ for some $p\in\Gamma$ and $x_0\mapsto\gamma(x_0)$ is a parametrization of $\Gamma$ by arclength $x_0\in(-l,l)$. Also we define the following coordinate system $G$ in a neighborhood of $(x_0,x):=(x_0,\bar{x},x_N)\in\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$ as $$G(x_0,x):=F(x_0,\bar{x})-x_N{\bf n}(F(x_0,\bar{x}))$$ where $\bf n$ is a unit outward normal to $\partial\Omega$. Then we can have the following expansion of $g_{ab}$ where $a,b\in\{0,\dots,N-1\}$ as $$\color{blue}{g_{ab}=\bar{g}_{ab}+2\bar{h}_{ab}x_N+\bar{k}_{ab}x_N^2+O(x_N^3)}$$ where $\bar{g}$ is the metric on $\partial\Omega$ in local coordinates $(x_0,\bar{x})$, also $\bar{h}_{ab}$ denotes the coefficients for second fundamental form of $\partial\Omega$ and $\bar{k}_{ab}=(\bar{h}\otimes\bar{h})_{ab}$ are the squares of the same.
I just want to know why the last expansion is valid in terms of $x_N$ and why the second fundamental form plays a crucial role here. Any help is appreciated.
